# Disable all input fields on products edit page for specific admin role in admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, adminhtml, admin-panel, product-grid

Is there any way to disable all input fields on the product admin for a specific admin role in a custom module.

The specific admin role should only view the content but not have the access to edit/update them.

Comment: There is no way to archive your requirement, you need to do customization for it.

Comment: yes but how ? any idea ?

Comment: Find it by your self, and have us to help you on review your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try it like this**

**[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="[Vendor]_[Module]::hideattribute.phtml" name="after"/> 
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/templates/disableattribute.phtml**

```
<?php
    $role_id = 3; //user's role id for example I have used "3"
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $adminSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
    $current_adminuser =    $adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getRoleId();
?>
<?php if($role_id == $current_adminuser): ?>
    <style>
[data-index = status],[data-index = attribute_set_id],[data-index = attribute_set_id],[data-index = name],[data-index = sku],[data-index = tax_class_id],[data-index = container_weight],[data-index = container_category_ids],[data-index = visibility],[data-index = container_news_from_date],[data-index = country_of_manufacture],[data-index = activity] {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

just update `[data-index = yourattributeid]`
this is just an example do not use objectmanager and create a block and call them using factory method

Comment: happy to help......